# how to specify Google Map version in iOS using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I just got an email from Google Map Platform. it is said that

> during the second quarter of 2022, iOS 12 will not be supported in the
> upcoming SDK versions: Maps and Places SDKs for iOS v7.0 or higher.

and if I want to still continue to support iOS 12 and below. it is said that

> to prevent Xcode from loading the newest SDK version, specify version
> 6.x or lower for Maps and Places SDKs (when available) in your Podfile or Cartfile. We will release the new versions later this year.

it seems to me that I need to hardcode the version of google map in the Podfile. I can easily set it to be 6.x or lower in native iOS development (I just need to change the podfile).

but now I am using Flutter and I am using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) ^2.0.6 , I can't find GoogleMaps version in my podfile if using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

my question is, how to specify version 6.x or lower for Maps and Places SDKs in Flutter so I can keep supporting iOS 12 and below in my iOS Flutter app ?

Comment: Tried changing the Maps SDK version in the Podfile (`ios/Podfile.lock`), but it didn't work. It seems that `google_maps_flutter` is pinned to Maps SDK version that supports iOS 9 which is `4.1.0` as mentioned here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86820

Comment: @jabamataro so basically we have to still use certain version of google maps from pub.dev?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.